# Can anyone help me to change factor to date in r?

Tags: r, date

I imported a csv file with dates to R. The dataframe is named `DT`, and one of the column called `date` has year and month in it.

```
class(DT$date)
[1] "factor"

head(DT$date)
[1] 2013年1月 2013年1月 2013年1月 2013年1月 2013年1月 2013年1月
60 Levels: 2013年10月 2013年11月 2013年12月 2013年1月 ... 2017年9月
```

And I tried to use `as.Date` to convert it to date format:

```
date <- as.Date(DT$date, format = "%Y/%m")
date <- as.Date(as.factor(DT$date), format = "%Y/%m")
date <- as.Date(as.factor(DT$date), format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

During this operation I lose all my dates. Then I tried the `lubridate` package:

```
date <- ymd(DT$date)
date <- as.yearmon( DT$date)
```

However, I lose all my dates again. Can anyone help me to change this factor to Date in R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work:

```
DT = data.frame(date = c("2013年1月", "2013年11月", "2017年9月"))
lubridate::parse_date_time(DT$date, orders = "ym")
```

You should generally start with the `parse_date_time` function.

Comment: I used parse_date_time , but it still appear All formats failed to parse. No formats found

Comment: @user10147313 Did you run the two-line code and saw an error, or is this an error on your actual data? Because the code I posted work on every single one of my computers. What version of `lubridate` and `R` are you using? What is your `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: I use R 3.4.4 and my data is  DT <- as.data.table(read.table("/Users/Win10/Desktop/BDI測.csv", header=T, sep=",")) , then I typed library(lubridate)   Month_Yr <-parse_date_time(DT$date, orders = "ym") , it showed  960 failed to parse

Comment: Again, *are you seeing failure when you execute my code?*. What is the `nrow(DT)`? If you are seeing failure to parse for only a subset of the data, then it's the data's inconsistent formatting, as far as I can see.